# Compass File Location Best Practice

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Just starting out with SASS and Compass.

I've been using a Mac App called CodeKit to compile and manage my Sass and Compass.

If I wanted to use a set of Sass Partials on multiple projects and ideally store these in a central location (for example my dropbox) is this possible?

Codekit has a really nice feature called Frameworks that lets you do this but this doesn't work once you start to use Compass as Compass is a framework in its own right.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Compass extension](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/) and import it into your `config.rb`s.